Convert $\partial_{\beta}\partial_{\gamma}(\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}p_{\nu}p_{\beta})$ from index notation to vector notation
I have the expression $\partial_{\beta}\partial_{\gamma}(\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}p_{\nu}p_{\beta})$ written using Einstein summation convention with $\alpha$ the only free index, p is a vector in cartesian coordinates and all indicies represent x, y or z. I want to change this expression into vector/tensor notation.
My attempt:
$\partial_{\beta}\partial_{\gamma}(\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}p_{\nu}p_{\beta})$ = $\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}\partial_{\beta}(\partial_{\gamma}p_{\nu})p_{\beta}+\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}\partial_{\beta}(\partial_{\gamma}p_{\beta})p_{\nu}$
= $(\partial_{\beta}(\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}\partial_{\gamma}p_{\nu}))p_{\beta}+(\partial_{\beta}p_{\beta})\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}(\partial_{\gamma}p_{\nu})+\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}(\partial_{\beta}(\partial_{\gamma}p_{\beta}))p_{\nu}+\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}(\partial_{\beta}p_{\nu})(\partial_{\gamma}p_{\beta})$
I believe that: $(\partial_{\beta}(\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}\partial_{\gamma}p_{\nu}))p_{\beta} = [\nabla(\nabla\times p)p]\cdot p$ and $(\partial_{\beta}p_{\beta})\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}(\partial_{\gamma}p_{\nu}) = (\nabla\cdot p)(\nabla\times p)$
I do not know how to deal with the other two terms.
Thank you in advance for the help.

@NicholasTodoroff I made a typo in my question sorry, one of the betas was supposed to be a gamma.

I'm not sure what you're trying to write for the first term, it doesn't make much sense. Consider instead moving $p_\beta$ to the front, and also know that $p\cdot\nabla$ is a valid expression (and that it is a differential operator where $p$ itself is not differentiated).
For the third term, remember that partial derivatives commute.
The last term is impossible to express using standard vector calculus. It is something that I would notate
$$
  (\dot\nabla\cdot\check p)(\check\nabla\times\dot p)
$$
but this is nonstandard. The logic is that $\dot\nabla$ is differentiating $\dot p$ and $\check\nabla$ is differentiating $\check p$. Standard vector calculus solely uses a differentiate-to-the-right convention like single variable calculus, but unlike the single variable you cannot write every expression you want to using the differentiate-to-the-right convention.

There is an alternative:
Commute partials at the outset and only apply the product rule once:
$$
  \partial_\beta\partial_\gamma(\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}p_\nu p_\beta) = \partial_\gamma\partial_\beta(\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}p_\nu p_\beta) = \partial_\gamma[\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}(\partial_\beta p_\nu) p_\beta + \epsilon_{\alpha\gamma\nu}p_\nu(\partial_\beta p_\beta)].
$$
I promise that you can write both these terms as vector calculus expressions.

Thank you so much! I believe using your suggestion gives: $\nabla\times(p\cdot\nabla)p+(p\times\nabla)(\nabla\cdot p)$. The fact that some expressions cannot be written in vector calculus notation is fascinating.

@ArchieBrew Almost, two things: (1) In the first term I would use brackets $\nabla\times[(p\cdot\nabla)p]$ to make it clear what $\nabla\times$ is applied to. (2) In the second term $\partial_\gamma$ needs to be differentiating $p_\nu$ as well. It should be $\nabla\times[(\nabla\cdot p)p]$.

Oh yes thanks, I have no idea what was going through my head for that second term
